# Why aren't degree modifiers complements?

Tags: grammar, modifiers, complements, syntactic-analysis

As far as I've been able to figure out, in the CaGEL* framework, complements are items that are licensed by some other element (generally the head), so that if an item has to be licensed, it is per definition a complement. But if I've got this right, then how come degree modifiers aren't complements? I mean, they elaborate on a feature that is only found with a subgroup of heads, just like any complement?

*Huddleston, R., and Pullum, G. K., 2002. *The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language*. Cambridge: Cambridge University Press.

Comment: *That is very weird*.   Are you saying that **very** is a complement of **weird** because **weird** is a matter of degree and thus licenses **very**?   Aren't complements *required* not merely *licensed*?

Comment: No, a degree modifier like "very" can occur with many adjectives. Complements, by definition, can be required or permitted.

Comment: A small request: In its index the CGEL has several entries for _degree modification_ and even more for _complement_. It would be helpful (at least for indolent CGEL users such as me) if you could tell us the page(s) you are referring to.

Comment: @TRomano Well, I'm not saying it is, since I know it isn't – I'm asking **why** it isn't, considering the definition of complements as something that is licensed by a subgroup of heads only. And no, as far as I've understood it, complements aren't necessarily required.

Comment: @BillJ with many, yes, but far from all. So I don't quite see the difference really between a feature of degree, which is limited to a subgroup of heads, and a feature of, say 'goal', as found with goal complements, found with a subgroup of verbs.

Comment: @Shoe if your comment was meant for me, I'm sorry, but I'm not referring to any pages in particular, just to the general understanding of licensing and complementation as presented in the CaGEL framework...

Comment: Thanks. The CGEL is a mighty tome and it often takes me quite a while to track down what I am looking for. According to the index _complementation_ is dealt with in 30-40 different pages or page ranges, hence my request for a shortcut.

Comment: That's not true.There are a huge number of adjectives of all kinds that can be modified by "very", so we can hardly say that "very" only occurs with some subgroup of them. Further, items like "very" are always optional, unlike complements which either have to be licensed, or else are obligatory for some reason, such as being required to complete a VP, or for the particular sense of some head. Also, AdjPs license complements in post-head structure ("Ed is afraid of spiders"), while "very" occurs in attributive position.

Comment: Why is *of spiders* considered a complement there and not simply an adjunct presenting the source of Ed's fearful state? In  *Ed is afraid for his life*  is *for his life* also a complement?

Comment: The PP qualifies as a complement by virtue of being licensed by the head, i.e. "afraid".

Comment: @BillJ Thanks! I still don't quite get how heads with a feature of degree don't form a subclass, seeing that we can clearly divide e.g. adjectives into those that can, and those that can't be modified by *very*, but your other points make a lot of sense. :)

Comment: @TRomano I **think** the reasons we say that *of spiders* is a complement are that (i) the adjective selects precisely an *of*-phrase; you can't replace the preposition with some other preposition, nor can you use an *of*-phrase freely as a modifier with other adjectives (this, I think, is what BillJ means in his comment to you), and (ii) it elaborates on a very salient and important part of the meaning of *afraid*; just like a transitive verb sets up a slot for an object, *afraid* very clearly sets up a slot for the cause of the fear. (I hope someone will correct me if I'm wrong...)

Comment: @Shoe Agreed! :) But, alas, no shortcut available in this case...

Comment: @BillJ:  and Hannah: How can you know when something is "licensed"?  *Ed is afraid. Ed is afraid of the dark. Ed is afraid for his life. Ed is afraid **in** the dark.*  Is it when the verb+preposition combination creates a "recognized" (lexicalized) sub-meaning? Or is it when the combination has a quasi-transitive sense?  *afraid-of* (fears), possibly *afraid-for* (is anxious about threats to) but not *afraid-in*?

Comment: @TRomano :) :) :) I'm struggling with these precise questions. I find the whole concept of licensing very vague and hard to understand – the idea of limited subset (which is what my OP is about) being one aspect i don't get; the things you ask here being others.